# How do i validate a barcode number using php

Tags: php, validation, barcode

I have a database full of user user entered Barcode numbers of variious lengths.

How can I validate these barcode values to determine if the are correct format, ie, length and check digit? using php

Comment: Ask yourself this question what needs to be validated to tell if it is a correct barcode? Then try to make this validations, if you get stuck then ask a question on SO with the code you've tried.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

here you go:

```
function isValidBarcode($barcode) {
        //checks validity of: GTIN-8, GTIN-12, GTIN-13, GTIN-14, GSIN, SSCC
        //see: http://www.gs1.org/how-calculate-check-digit-manually
        $barcode = (string) $barcode;
        //we accept only digits
        if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/", $barcode)) {
            return false;
        }
        //check valid lengths:
        $l = strlen($barcode);
        if(!in_array($l, [8,12,13,14,17,18]))
            return false;
        //get check digit
        $check = substr($barcode, -1);
        $barcode = substr($barcode, 0, -1);
        $sum_even = $sum_odd = 0;
        $even = true;
        while(strlen($barcode)>0) {
            $digit = substr($barcode, -1);
            if($even)
                $sum_even += 3 * $digit;
            else 
                $sum_odd += $digit;
            $even = !$even;
            $barcode = substr($barcode, 0, -1);
        }
        $sum = $sum_even + $sum_odd;
        $sum_rounded_up = ceil($sum/10) * 10;
        return ($check == ($sum_rounded_up - $sum));
    }
```

Comment: exist any way to get the typo based in https://mpdf.github.io/reference/html-control-tags/barcode.html

Comment: this seems wrong for GTIN-13 where the first digit should not be multiplied by 3, thus `$even` should be set to `false` , am I wrong?

Comment: @akabaka No, the first digit is _always_ the penultimate on the right hand side.

Answer (score 1):

I've used PHPBarcodeChecker in a project, take a look here: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/8560-PHP-Detect-type-and-check-EAN-and-UPC-barcodes.html

Hope it helps!